# ctx.fillText does not draw on connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, html5-canvas

For some reason ctx.fillText does not want to draw absolutely anything when client connects to the server. Console is logging everything properly so the function works but the canvas is being a bit silly.

Here's a chunk of the server-side code:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

  socket.id = Math.random();
  SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;

  console.log(":: Client Connected -- " + Date());
});

setInterval(function(){

 for(var i in SOCKET_LIST){
    var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];

    socket.emit('PlayerID', {
        id: socket.id
    });
 }

}, 1000/25);
```

And the client side:

```
<canvas id="ctx" width="800" height="500" style="border: 1px solid #000;"></canvas> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io();

    var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");


    socket.on('PlayerID', function(data){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 500);
        ctx.fillText('Client', 0, 0); // (data.id.toString(), 0, 0)
        console.log(data.id);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ctx.fillText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textBaseline) positions text according to the current [textBaseline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textBaseline), font, textAlign and direction values.

`fillText( txt, 0, 0)` positions non descending text above the canvas by default. Inserting `ctx.textBaseline = "top";` and/or increasing the y coordinate value passed in the call to `fillText` can be used to reposition the text to make it visible.

Comment: That re-positioned it! Thank you!